# Saving a file in Mongodb's GridFS with pymongo results in a truncated file - python 2.7 on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

Saving a file in Mongodb's GridFS with pymongo results in a truncated file.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import gridfs
import os

#just to make sure we aren't crazy, check the filesize on disk:
print os.path.getsize( r'owl.jpg' )

#add the file to GridFS, per the pymongo documentation: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/gridfs.html
db = MongoClient().myDB
fs = gridfs.GridFS( db )
fileID = fs.put( open( r'owl.jpg', 'r')  )
out = fs.get(fileID)
print out.length
```

On Windows 7, running this program generates this output:

```
145047
864
```

On Ubuntu, running this program generates this (correct) output:

```
145047
145047
```

Unfortunately, the application I'm working on is targeting the Windows OS...

Any help would be appreciated!

so you can reproduce my example more rigorously, 'owl.jpg' was downloaded from:   http://getintobirds.audubon.org/sites/default/files/photos/wildlife_barn_owl.jpg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Heh, changing

```
fileID = fs.put( open( r'owl.jpg', 'r')  )
```

to:

```
fileID = fs.put( open( r'owl.jpg', 'rb')  )
```

Fixes the behavior of the program on Windows 7.  Too bad the behavior is different between OS's...

Comment: Even on Linux I had to open the file with 'rb' or else I would get "'str' does not support buffer interface" error

Comment: python 3 require the file to be open in binary mode or you will get utf decoding error (or another system default string decoder)

Answer (score 5):

you already got the answer, but for the curious:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. **Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files**; the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading and writing such files.